# How to set DeployIisAppPath as a variable based on build configuration?

Tags: msbuild

I want to have one build for my project that handles creating artifacts for the test and release environments. I'm stuck on how to make the DeployIisAppPath variable configurable based on build configuration. For example, for the test build, I want to set the path to "Default Web Site/test folder", but in production (Release), I need it to be "some other site/different folder". This value is normally passed in to the Visual Studio Team Services build definition via an MSBuild argument. Can I do this with variable, and if so, how? Can these values be set in the project itself?

I can't find anything online that helps me figure out HOW to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a solution for your problem.

It is possible to define Publish Profiles in Visual Studio to publish (WCF/web service) projects.

Previously define Build Configurations that should be used to build for each of your environments, e.g. DEV, TEST, QA, PROD. In these you could define different output directories and the best, you could generate for each of them an own web.config transformation file. That is very important if you want to use different database server connection strings on different stages, only as example.

After creating Build Configurations, just open context menu on the (web service) project and select `Publish...` there you should set up a publish profile like followed:

1. use target environment/stage as name (same like Build Configuration
   for meaningful naming)
2. Publish Method: *Web Deploy Package*
3. Package location: a place where you could grab it with your release pipeline
4. Site name: "Default Web Site/test folder" (for your test environment) || "some other site/different folder" (for your prod
   environment)
5. set build configuration that was previously set up and is for target environment

An example for the points above (in same order):

1. Name: TEST
2. Publish Method: Web Deploy Package
3. Package location: ....\BuildDrop\TEST\My.WebService.zip)
4. Site name: "Default Web Site/test_service"
5. Configuration: TEST (like previously defined)

You have not to publish now, but if you want to you could do. Than you will receive a zip file with your web service and some other files beside that are needed for deployment by MSDeploy.exe in your release pipeline.

After that you should switch to your build pipeline in TFS. There you have to create a variable for your stages. Therefore you have to enable multi-configuration in options of your build definition (`edit Build definition > Options > Multi-configuration > enable it, add as multipliers "BuildConfiguration"`).
In build definition's edit mode you have to add a variable named BuildConfiguration with value `"DEV, TEST, QA, PROD"`. This variable is now usable in build task. Just add it in build task in configuration's textbox as `$(BuildConfiguration)`.
Now for every build configuration that was added to variable separated by ',' a build process will be executed.
To create the artefact (zip file from above) you have to add some MSBuild arguments and at this point you will use your publish profiles that have the same name like your build configurations. That's the trick! :)
The argument list is lik followed:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=$(BuildConfiguration)
```

This argument list will result in needed artifacts for the publishing based on each build configuration/publish profile. Now you have for each build configuration and thereby for your environments a separate configuration like your mentioned different DeployIisAppPath.

To use the artifacts in your release definition you have to add a `Publish Artifact` (in TFS 2017) task in your build definition. Than it is possible to use a Batch task to publish your web service automatically by executing the batch file from defined Package location. An example configuration would be:

```
Path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<YourBuildDefinitionName>/<YourTargetSatgeName>/My.WebService.cmd
Arguments: /Y /M:<TargetMachineName>
```

I hope I could help you. If you have any questions or some points/descriptions are unclear, please let me know...